# Is there a maximum character limit for sybase columns using the AseDataAdapter.Fill() method?

Tags: c#, sybase

I have a really long string in one of the columns of my Sybase table (over 45k characters) that I am trying to read using AseDataAdapter.Fill(). I noticed that it cuts off my string and only reads in 32,768 characters. Is there a limit on the string size I can read in? Can the max length be changed?

```
command.CommandTimeout = timeout;
command.CommandText = strQuery;

AseDataAdapter sAdapter = new AseDataAdapter(command);
sAdapter.Fill(dSet, strDataSetName);
```

I've also noticed that the System.Data.DataSet object has column type of object(string) as opposed to string. I'm not sure if that type has a smaller character limit and is the source of the truncation

Comment: assuming this is a Sybase ASE database ... a string of 45K characters would need to be stored in a column of type 'text'; the default max number of bytes (aka 'characters' for a single-byte charset) that ASE will return (from a text column) is 32K (32768) bytes; for a (i)sql session the max can be increased via the 'set textsize #####'; if your driver doesn't have a setting for increasing the textsize then can you submit a 'set textsize #####' command prior to issuing your 'select' query; [NOTE: I don't work with c# so not sure what options you have via c#]

Comment: Yeah, setting text size worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just to have a clear answer with supporting data-

There is a limit on no. of characters to be read in SELECT clause. By default it is set to 32KB. Here is the Sybase documentation:
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc34201_1500/html/dco_150/dco_150126.htm

If you check this in you DB you can see the same limit:

```
1> select @@textsize
2> go

 -----------
       32768

(1 row affected)
```

To increase this limit, simply use the following command and you will see most of the data you could not read: (NOTE: max is 2GB = 2000000000 bytes)

```
1> set textsize 2000000000
2> go
1> select @@textsize
2> go

 -----------
    2000000000
```